# Дебаг linux kernel

Tags: linux, отладка, kernel, gdb

Пытаюсь произвести дебаг ядра linux. Столкнулся с проблемами, на которые не получается найти ответ, поэтому прошу помощи у вас. Для начала как я все делаю:
На отлаживаемую машину, загружаю ядро с включенными флагами дебага

```
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y

CONFIG_KGDB=y

CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y

CONFIG_KGDB_KDB=y

CONFIG_KDB_KEYBOARD=y
```

В файле загрузчика прописываю

```
kgdboc=ttymxc1,115200 kgdbwait
```

После чего при запуске ядра получаю

```
[    2.340109] KGDB: Registered I/O driver kgdboc
[    2.375570] KGDB: Waiting for connection from remote gdb...
```

Далее на другой машине запускаю

```
sudo gdb-multiarch vmlinux
```

и подключаюсь к отлаживаемой машине

```
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0
```

подключение проходит успешно и gdb отвечает мне где мы находимся

```
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyUSB0
kgdb_cpu_enter (ks=0x0, regs=0x730, exception_state=-1050376452)
    at kernel/debug/debug_core.c:671
671     kgdb_info[cpu].enter_kgdb--;
```

Теперь к проблемам:
Куда бы я не ставил брекпоинты(я проходил step'ами и ставил брейкпоинт на функцию которую он точно проходит) он их игнорирует и после continue просто происходит загруза ядра. Собственно вопрос где я делаю ошибки, что я делаю не так.
Так же мне бы хотелось отладить модули которые загружены в ядро( я пытался ставить на их функции брейки, но ничего не происходит).
Иногда после continue gdb просто отваливается, а ядро просто продолжает загружаться.

Comment: Для отладки модулей надо `gdb` рассказать про символы и адреса линковки.

Comment: Написал несколько драйверов, вполне себе сложных. И **никогда** не пользовался отладчиком. Вся работа ядра построена на прерываниях, блокировках и т.д... Любое вмешательство в эту тонкую материю приводит просто к не определённым результатам. Всё время пользовался *printk* и никаких проблем не возникало. Ну как вы под отладчиком определите - успевает Ваш драйвер обрабатывать данные, или не успевает ?!